# Emacs Lisp Macro Does Not Expand Alist

Tags: emacs, elisp-macro

Here's my macro, what it is supposed to do is to wrap a `body` in `let` with bindings from `vars-alist`

```
(defmacro with-vars-alist (vars-alist &rest body)
  `(let (,@(mapcar (lambda (cell) (list (car cell) (cdr cell))) vars-alist))
     ,@body))
```

When I am looking at what it expands to using following code

```
(defvar my-vars-alist '((var1 . "var1")
                        (var2 . "var2")))
(macroexpand-1 (with-vars-alist my-vars-alist `(concat ,var1 ,var2)))
```

I get an error `cons: Wrong type argument: sequencep, my-vars-alist`

However checking it `(sequencep my-vars-alist)` return `t`.

The error is probably has some simple solution, but I am just unable to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that arguments to macros are *un-evaluated*, which means that when you pass `my-vars-alist` as an argument, it is passed verbatim as the *symbol* `my-vars-alist`.

Therefore during the macro expansion, `vars-alist` evaluates to the symbol `my-vars-alist` rather than the list `((var1 . "var1") (var2 . "var2"))`.

So the error isn't complaining that the *variable* `my-vars-alist` doesn't *contain* a sequence as its value, but rather that the *symbol* `my-vars-alist` is not *itself* a sequence (which is correct -- it's a symbol).

> checking it `(sequencep my-vars-alist)` return `t`.

Which is also correct, as there `my-vars-alist` is evaluated as a variable to its value of `((var1 . "var1") (var2 . "var2"))`

So you need to `eval` that argument. e.g.:

```
,@(mapcar (lambda (cell) (list (car cell) (cdr cell)))
          (eval vars-alist))
```

As `vars-alist` is *already* being evaluated to the symbol `my-vars-alist`, this change means that we are passing that symbol `my-vars-alist` to `eval`, which evaluates it as a variable to obtain the list needed for `mapcar`.

---

You probably also wanted to quote the form you pass to `macroexpand-1` (or use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`).

Comment: Thanks. It works. My thought was, that since `vars-alist` is prepended by `,@` it will be evaluated. I tried using `,` but it doesn't work complaining about `(void-function \,)`

Comment: Yes, `vars-alist` *is* evaluated within the `,@(...)` form -- it is evaluated to the symbol `my-vars-alist`. Therefore `(eval vars-alist)` is passing `my-vars-alist` to `eval` and obtaining the list value to pass to `mapcar`.  Note that trying to use `,vars-alist` within that form can't work because that implies a second level of nested backquoting which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I looks like what you're trying to do is let-bind the keys of an alist to their values, so you can use the keys as variables in the let body.  There's a built in macro for this in recent Emacs:

```
(let-alist '((a . 1) (b . 2))
  (message "a: %d, b: %d" .a .b))
```